# Laravel, multiple checkbox for delete and button edit in the same view

Tags: laravel, forms, edit, sql-delete

I have to insert in the same view a edit button and multiple checkboxes to delete records in DB. The edit button works only for the first record, the checkbox delete only for the last even if i check multiple options. The functions works if there is edit button or delete checkboxes alone, not together.

```
@isset($lista)
<table>
    <th>Lista degli utenti Staff: </th>
    <tr>
        <td> Nome </td>
        <td> Cognome </td>
        <td> Username </td>
        <td> Modifica </td>
        <td> Elimina </td>
        @foreach ($lista as $staff)
        <tr>
        <td>{{$staff->nome}} </td>
        <td> {{$staff->cognome}} </td>
        <td> {{$staff->username}} </td>
        <td>
            {{ Form::open(array( 'route'=> ['modificastaff', $staff->id],'method'=>'post')) }}
            {{ Form::submit('Modifica') }}
            {{ Form::close() }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ Form::open(array( 'route'=> ['eliminastaff'],'method'=>'post')) }}
            {{ Form::checkbox('checked[]', $staff->id) }}
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
{{ Form::submit('Elimina') }}  
{{ Form::close() }}
</table>  
@endisset
```

Comment: There is an error in your HTML. You are missing a closing `</tr>` tag before the `@foreach`. I doubt that it has anything to do with your problem, but you should still probably fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first form inside the table is fine.  You open it, ask for `submit` and then close it within its loop / `<tr>`.

The issue you are having is because you are opening multiple forms for your checkbox and they are **not closing within the loop / table**.  This means you are opening multiple forms on top of each other and on top of the edit form, which is causing the error.

**To fix, change this**:

```
<td>
        {{ Form::open(array( 'route'=> ['eliminastaff'],'method'=>'post')) }}
        {{ Form::checkbox('checked[]', $staff->id) }}
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
{{ Form::submit('Elimina') }}  
{{ Form::close() }}
```

**to this:**

```
    <td>
        {{ Form::open(array( 'route'=> ['eliminastaff'],'method'=>'post')) }}
        {{ Form::checkbox('checked[]', $staff->id) }}
        {{ Form::submit('Elimina') }}  
        {{ Form::close() }}
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

If you want to accept multiple checks, you will have to re-architect this a bit.  But this will solve your issue for the 1st edit / last delete error you were having.

Comment: My goal is that the submit 'Elimina' accepts multiple checks, how can i architect this?

Comment: That's a different question.  Does this answer solve your original problem?  For multiple checks, you have to have something to loop on.  With your code,you have a single staff person in that row.  This would allow for THAT ONE staff person to be deleted.  If you want to have multiple staff deleted from the same table, I suggest you remove the form elements (b/c you cannot have a form over the whole table on top of another form) and use some javascript to accept a submit button at the bottom of the table (not inside a form).  This will allow any staff to delete but not break HTML form rules.

Comment: You can leave the initial edit box as a form - that works fine.   But I would probably have some `onclick()` method at the bottom that looks to see which `id`s are checked for delete, then send that to your server.  Not a form, but still does the same thing :)